# SFTP remove files from remote with local script

Tags: shell, sftp

I have a local script, i want to remove a file from the remote via the local script.
I tried the following way below but it does not work. I have permissions to delete in the remote.

```
#!bin/sh
USER=test_user
HOST=xx.xx.xxx.xx
REMOTE_DIR=/somedirectoryinremote

while true
  do
    sftp $USER@$HOST:$REMOTE_DIR "rm -f $REMOTE_DIR/*.txt"
    # sftp rm $USER@$HOST:$REMOTE_DIR/*.txt <- tried this but does not work too.
    sleep 1800
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :-

```
echo "rm $REMOTE_DIR/*.txt" |sftp $USER@$HOST:$REMOTE_DIR
```

If you can sftp, can you not run ssh? ssh will be more simple.

```
ssh $USER@$HOST "rm -f $REMOTE_DIR/*.txt"
```